# PostgreSQL, storing encrypted data or encrypt database with pgcrypto - what is more secure?

Tags: postgresql, security, postgresql-9.3

I have two machines: client and server (a database server). I want to connect from client to server and manipulate data from database (insert, update, delete, select) using `dblink`.

I would like to ask what is more secure:

1. Encrypting data on client side, send them to the server from client as ciphertext and then store in `PostgreSQL` database
2. Send data from client to server and do the encryption/decryption on server side with `pgcrytpto`?

Is that secure that server obtains the encryption key temporarily (for the time of one of possible operations only) from client / other server? Im wondering if there's a possibility that no matter if server obtains a key only temporarily, is there still posibility that the key will be available in `PostgreSQL` server's logs (or any other database server) somehow?

Comment: "Security" is largely meaningless without context. What do you want to protect your data from?

Comment: @Tometzky: My question is: is there any chance that even temporarily obtained key will be visible in database server logs? (And thats it - it will show that using encryption/decryption provided with the database(e.g. `pgcrypto` isnt a good idea at all - isnt secure).

Comment: This has been cloned to http://stackoverflow.com/q/21865246/398670. Please don't copy and paste questions between sites. It wastes everybody's time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it is certainly possible that a key used in pgcrypto function would end up in server logs or leak somewhere else.

Postgres could be configured to log long running queries (and for example password hash functions are long running by design) or even all of them. There are utilities that show current running queries. Or an error in a query can leak it in an error message.

So, if I had a choice, I'd use cryptographic functions from a frontend language.